# CMake list wxWidgets Dll and copy them on install

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets

The cmake script FindwxWidgets create the list of all .lib files.

However this script does not provide the list of wxWidgets dlls.

What is the CMake script to store in a list all wxWidgets Dll file for debug and release targets ?

ps: I found some project based on wxWidgets and CMake but they all link statically with wxWidgets.

Work in progress:

The current dirty solution is to fetch all dll's in the wxWidgets directory and install in the same folder as the exe. However there is no filter for used components as it is not linked with the find_package command.

`# Copy wxWidgets Dll's
    # extract folder path

    file(GLOB wxwidgets_dlls "${wxWidgets_LIB_DIR}/*.dll")
    list(APPEND WXWidgets_DLL_Slash "")
    foreach(WXWidgets_DLL ${wxwidgets_dlls})
        # Check if dll does not contain "ud" for debug dll
        get_filename_component(DLL_FILENAME ${WXWidgets_DLL}  NAME_WE)
        string(FIND ${DLL_FILENAME} "ud" debug_annot)
        if(${debug_annot} LESS 0)
            string(REPLACE "\\" "/" WXWidgets_DLL ${WXWidgets_DLL})
            MESSAGE(STATUS "Install ${WXWidgets_DLL}")
            list(APPEND WXWidgets_DLL_Slash ${WXWidgets_DLL})
        endif()
    endforeach(WXWidgets_DLL)

    install(FILES
            ${WXWidgets_DLL_Slash}
            DESTINATION .)`

Comment: Not sure if your project has to use CMake, but if not, why dont you compile wxWidgets without CMake? It is fairly easy...

Comment: @macroland I do not compile wxWidgets, I compile a project that link to wxWidgets. However with dynamic linking the final executable require wxWidgets Dlls. So I have to find a way to find and copy theses Dll's using CMake.

Comment: I would vote to close your question, because it is not clear what you actually want. Can give a minimal example that shows what you currently have and what it lacks with respect to what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of [what](https://gitlab.com/nazarmx/CGGD/blob/5ed4c4c157e8e73b9b7b102cacde78fecb4c7ded/src/CMakeLists.txt) I use together with CPack. It will analyse the `.exe` with `dumpbin`/`readelf` to find what libraries to copy.

My script also tries to strip the resulting DLL's (you can remove that part if you want). Insert this **after** your `install(TARGETS ...)` command.

Things you might need to adjust (careful, they will be expanded before install time):

- `RUNTIME_DIR` - subdirectory like `bin` where your `.exe` and `.dll` files are installed
- `EXECUTABLE_NAME` - name of your target without the `.exe`
- Third parameter to `fixup_bundle` - its `\"\"` but you might need to change it to `\"${wxWidgets_LIB_DIR}\"` (the directory from which to copy the dlls)

```
install(CODE "
    include(BundleUtilities)
    fixup_bundle(\"\$ENV{DESTDIR}\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${RUNTIME_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX}\" \"\" \"\")
    file(GLOB dynamic_libs \"\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${RUNTIME_DIR}/*${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}*\")
    message(STATUS \"GLOB: \${dynamic_libs}\")
    foreach(dll IN LISTS dynamic_libs)
        if(\"${CMAKE_STRIP}\")
            execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_STRIP} \"-s\" \${dll})
        endif()
    endforeach(dll)
")
```

Update: `install(CODE ...)` adds commands inside of string to `cmake_install.cmake` file verbatim, so generator expressions are not expanded.
Number of useful variables is also quite limited, for example `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` in my example is expanded inside `cmake_install.cmake`, but `${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}` should be expanded before going there.

You can try using `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}`/`\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` to create full path to `.exe` manually.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that tomorrow and give a feedback.

Comment: I try using $<TARGET_FILE:isimpa> that should be evaluated to the final exe name but this variable does not expand.

Comment: @nicolas-f Sorry, generator expressions won't work in this case. `install (CODE ..)` simply adds the commands in string to `cmake_install.cmake` file. In that file generator expressions are not expanded and a lot of variables are missing (we have `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` available, but `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX` has to be expanded manually beforehand)

Comment: It seems to work, thank you. But I still have error messages https://ci.appveyor.com/project/nicolas-f/i-simpa/build/1.0.17#L4922

Comment: @nicolas-f `warning :cannot resolve item 'MSVCR71.dll'` is OK, since this library is part of MSVC redistributable. If you mean some other errors, then make a new question

Comment: I don't understand what is the goal of the foreach loop ?

Comment: @nicolas-f all code after `fixup_bundle` is optional: in my example I also try to [`strip`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/what-are-stripped-and-not-stripped-executables-in-unix) the libraries to make them smaller, the foreach iterates over filenames of `.dll` files

Comment: Ah ok. As I will use breakpad I will not strip dll. Other things. I don't understand why CPack does not include the dll into the final setup file.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to escape ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}. (http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2011-March/043504.html)

Comment: I found a way with win32 build to get the good folder of exe before install (other exe in install folder are scanned by fix bundle and may throw errors): https://github.com/nicolas-f/I-Simpa/commit/f843a97e513e522a94a9fb4c47fbbbcb8f5ddec9